# Getting physical location of files in an IPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am new to IOS App Development. I am working in an IOS app for IPad that will read a json file which will have names of some audio files. It will then play those files. I have copied the files into iPad using FilesOnTree App (http://download.cnet.com/FilesOnTree-FREE-Tree-File-Explorer/3000-2064_4-75748813.html). I can now only see the files in this app. I want my iPad app to access this data. For that I will need physical location of these files in iPad. Is there a way to get the physical location of files in iPad.

And after getting the address of files, will it be possible to access the files from my app.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access file outside of your App's Sandbox, except if the files are shared by the system (i.e. photo library and music files), after obtaining the proper permission from the user.

If these are music files, like you say, you can access them through [`MPMediaQuery`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaQuery_ClassReference/index.html)
and play them back with [`MPMusicPlayerController`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/index.html)

Comment: How to add files to my app's sandbox?

By adding it to project and deploying it?

Comment: Correctly. But as I said, for music files, you can use the iTunes phone library